# enabling rdp port on centos

Tags: centos, rdp

I have followed the tutorial and enabled the port 3389 , but still I am not able to connect to it . Any help is greatly appreciated

http://ajmatson.net/wordpress/2014/01/install-xrdp-remote-desktop-to-centos-6-5/

Comment: any error messages? what happens when you try to connect?

Comment: It says "Cannot connect to the remote machine" . I am using mstsc to connect to the machine.

Comment: Have you tried using telnet or nc to connect to port 3389 to try to get a more descriptive error?

Comment: Never used XRDP, but are you sure the services are running (what do `/etc/init.d/vncserver status` and `/etc/init.d/xrdp status` say), that port 3389 is listening (`netstat -tulpn`) and check iptables to find out if the port is really open (`iptables -nL`).